# Showing a "thank you" message after submiting a Contact Form

Tags: javascript, popup, message, contact-form

I have a working Contact Form on my website. The submit button leads to a .php file that is sending an e-mail (User doesn't see this step) and redirect user to contact form again.

I wanna make a simple message on the center of the screen after clicking the submit button. Something like "Thank you for sending the application".

I tried to set a variable in the php file

```
$mailSent = 1;
```

and then catch it in the script

```
var mailSent = "<?php echo $mailSent; ?>";
```

Then I wanted to do a simple if statement and style.display the message cotnainer. Sadly it didn't work out, I was getting the undefined errors.

```
if (mailSent == 1) {
    document.querySelector('.thankYouMessage').style.display = 'flex';
}
```

I wanted to ask you if you have any ideas on how to do it. I want the message to look like a bootstrap modal.

This is my contact form:

```
<div class="contact-form-container">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="POST">
                    <h1 class="lang" key="contact-form" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 22px; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ff4800; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 4px; font-weight: 100; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Formularz kontaktowy</h1>

                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-name" for=""></label>
                    <input id="name" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="name" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-email" for=""></label>
                    <input id="email" class="contact-form-content" type="email" name="email" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-topic" for=""></label>
                    <input id="topic" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="topic" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-text" for=""></label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" style="line-height:16px; font-size: 14px; font-family: calibri;" class="contact-form-content" cols="" rows="10"></textarea>
                    
                    <button class="contact-form-content-submit" name="submit" type="submit"><p class="lang" key="contact-form-send" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Wyślij</p><img id ="Contact_icon_white" src="img/Contact_icon_white.png" alt="White contact icon"></button>  
                </form>
                <div class="contact-form-callnow" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <p class="lang" key="callnow" id="contact-form-callnow" style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 14px 0px 4px 0px;">Zadzwoń teraz i umów przeprowadzkę!</p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><img src="img/Phone_icon_green.png" alt="Phone icon" style="height: 28px; padding-right: 10px"></a>
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><p style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 20px;">732 739 751</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my php Contact-form-handler

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $topic = $_POST['topic'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = "xyz@xyz.pl";

    $subject = "Tu ".$name.". Wiadomość do xyz";

    $headers = "From: ".$visitor_email;

    $txt = "\nNowa wiadomość od: ".$name."\n\n\nTemat:\n".$topic."\n\n\nWiadomość:\n".$message;

    mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);

    header ('Location: contact.php');  

} else {

    header ('location: index.php');

}
```

?>

Comment: *"I was getting the undefined errors"* ... from what specific part of the code and what variable?

Comment: In the contact-form-handler, just before the headr ('Location: contact.php'); line.

Comment: Ok but that doesn't say what specifically was undefined. What does the actual message tell you? Seems like you have multiple issues here ,

Comment: I'm getting " Undefined variable: mailSent" in the contact.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an already parsed php code. PHP code is parsed to HTML code first, and you are adding the PHP code again to your Javascript code.

Add this:

```
$mailSent = false;
```

If your mail is successfully sent, switch that variable to `true`. Then:

```
<?php
if($mailSent === true) {
?>
    <div class="success"></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

**Edit:** Try This:

```
<?php

$mailSent = false;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "marcincelmer95@gmail.com";

        $subject = "Tu ".$name.". Wiadomość do poznanprzeprowadzki.pl";

        $headers = "From: ".$visitor_email;

        $txt = "\nNowa wiadomość od: ".$name."\n\n\nTemat:\n".$topic."\n\n\nWiadomość:\n".$message;

        mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);

        $mailSent = true;

}

?>

<?php
if ($mailSent === true) {
?>
<div class="success">Mail is succesfully sent.</div>
<?php
}
?>

<div class="contact-form-container">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="contact.php" method="POST">
                    <h1 class="lang" key="contact-form" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 22px; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ff4800; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 4px; font-weight: 100; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Formularz kontaktowy</h1>

                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-name" for=""></label>
                    <input id="name" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="name" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-email" for=""></label>
                    <input id="email" class="contact-form-content" type="email" name="email" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-topic" for=""></label>
                    <input id="topic" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="topic" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-text" for=""></label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" style="line-height:16px; font-size: 14px; font-family: calibri;" class="contact-form-content" cols="" rows="10"></textarea>
                    
                    <button class="contact-form-content-submit" name="submit" type="submit"><p class="lang" key="contact-form-send" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Wyślij</p><img id ="Contact_icon_white" src="img/Contact_icon_white.png" alt="White contact icon"></button>  
                </form>
                <div class="contact-form-callnow" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <p class="lang" key="callnow" id="contact-form-callnow" style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 14px 0px 4px 0px;">Zadzwoń teraz i umów przeprowadzkę!</p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><img src="img/Phone_icon_green.png" alt="Phone icon" style="height: 28px; padding-right: 10px"></a>
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><p style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 20px;">732 739 751</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I try to do it your way. It just sends an e-mail and head it back to the contact.php.

Maybe I have to include something?

Now I tried to do an onclick function on the submit button of contact form. I submit the form, the "thank you" message shows up and then the page sadly refreshes... It's because in css my message has display:none and after the onclick function it's display:flex for a mooment.

Comment: I personally send the post action to the same page with the form. If your forms are in contact.php, action would point to contact.php too. Then you check if your request is post and your proper post key is set, you would show it in the same contact.php. Your "header location" is unnecessary. Somehow I feel you are not using a MVC system. Am I right? Because your project felt so untidied.

Please give me more abstract information about your project, so I can help you more.

Comment: I,m not using MVC, to be honest i don,t know what that is... So I have to post my php mailer code inside contact.php and delete the file contact-form-handler.php that was sending the mail earlier? That makes a lot of sense, i'll try that later and if I fail again i'll try to show my code more specifically :)

Comment: I am using Laravel as a MVC framework when I work with PHP. Highly recommend. I don't have an extreme info about plain PHP, but I think, when you redirect to another page, you lose the all post request data. That's why your post data becomes undefined. Instead of this, learn how to use a MVC framework like Laravel. You won't go anywhere without a pattern like MVC. Feel free to ask if you have a question.

Comment: hey Burak, I've posted my code above. If It can help you, this is my website's url:

https://www.poznanprzeprowadzki.pl

Comment: I edited my answer with the new code. Can you try it?

Comment: Finally... It works! I can add a div container or insert a script with querySelector :) It turns out that the if statement should be after the mailer? Thank you very much for your time and I will surely check out the MVC very soon.

Comment: Adding div container with if statement would be better than adding it with Javascript. If I summarize it: First add a variable for checking if the mail is sent, and attach it as false, then send your e-mail if you submit your form with a post request, if your mail is sent, make the variable true, and then if your variable is true, add a div alert to the html. And as I said, this would be okay to learn but migrating to a MVC system would be better choice. Have fun.

Comment: It is better because it's simplier? I did it by adding a div and it's actually good

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what are your trying to achieve. If you are using sensitive information with if clauses, you should use the if clauses at PHP code. But it's a simple check and/or you don't have to exhaust the server, you  can check it with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Now it looks like this:

```
<?php

$mailSent = 0;

echo $mailSent;

if ($mailSent === 1) {
    
    echo "<script>

        function myFunction() {
            document.querySelector('.modal-background').style.display = 'flex';
        };

    </script>";

}

else if ($mailSent === 0) {

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "marcincelmer95@gmail.com";

        $subject = "Tu ".$name.". Wiadomość do poznanprzeprowadzki.pl";

        $headers = "From: ".$visitor_email;

        $txt = "\nNowa wiadomość od: ".$name."\n\n\nTemat:\n".$topic."\n\n\nWiadomość:\n".$message;

        mail($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);

        $mailSent = 1;  

    } 

}

else {

}
```

?>

```
        <div class="contact-form-container">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form action="contact.php" method="POST">
                    <h1 class="lang" key="contact-form" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 22px; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ff4800; margin-bottom: 10px; padding-bottom: 4px; font-weight: 100; width: 100%; text-align: center;">Formularz kontaktowy</h1>

                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-name" for=""></label>
                    <input id="name" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="name" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-email" for=""></label>
                    <input id="email" class="contact-form-content" type="email" name="email" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-topic" for=""></label>
                    <input id="topic" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="topic" required>
                    
                    <label class="lang" key="contact-form-text" for=""></label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" style="line-height:16px; font-size: 14px; font-family: calibri;" class="contact-form-content" cols="" rows="10"></textarea>
                    
                    <button class="contact-form-content-submit" name="submit" type="submit"><p class="lang" key="contact-form-send" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">Wyślij</p><img id ="Contact_icon_white" src="img/Contact_icon_white.png" alt="White contact icon"></button>  
                </form>
                <div class="contact-form-callnow" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <p class="lang" key="callnow" id="contact-form-callnow" style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 14px 0px 4px 0px;">Zadzwoń teraz i umów przeprowadzkę!</p>
                </div>
                <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><img src="img/Phone_icon_green.png" alt="Phone icon" style="height: 28px; padding-right: 10px"></a>
                    <a style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" href="tel:+48732739751"><p style="font-family: Open Sans; margin: 0; padding: 4px 0px 10px 0px; font-size: 20px;">732 739 751</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The program echo's the $mailSent = 0, but despite the fact that it sends an email correctly, it does not overwrite the $mailSent variable...

I'm  a beggining programmer so I see this bugs for the first time in my life, sorry for being ignorant in some cases. I would love to learn frameworks but I feel like it's a bit too early for me to understand it all.

This is my website's URL if it helps somehow:

[www.poznanprzeprowadzki.pl](https://www.poznanprzeprowadzki.pl)